# How do we find the outward normal vector at a point $z_0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of a Jordan domain $\Omega$?

Tags: calculus

Let $\Omega$ be a Jordan Domain and $z_0$ a point on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. Suppose that $u(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable in some larger domain containing both $\Omega$ and $\partial \Omega$. The *outward normal derivative* of $u$ at $z_0 \in \partial \Omega$ is $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}(z_0)= \nabla u(z_0) \cdot N(z_0)$$
where $\nabla u(z_0)$ is the *gradient* of $u$ at $z_0$ and $N(z_0)$ is the *outward normal vector*.

Question: How do we calculate the outward normal vector $N(z_0)$ at the point $z_0$? Intuitively, I can tell what $N(z_0)$ looks like (a vector pointing straight out away from the domain $\Omega$ at the point $z_0 \in \partial \Omega$), but how do we find it given the information in the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$ are presented.

(i) If $\partial\Omega$ is given as a smooth curve
$$\partial\Omega:\quad t\mapsto z(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\qquad(a\leq t\leq b)$$
(or as a concatenation of such curves) going counterclockwise around $\Omega$ then an outward normal $n(t)$ at the point $z(t)$ is given by $n(t)=\bigl(y'(t),- x'(t)\bigr)$ (just turn the tangent vector $90^\circ$ clockwise). The vector $N$ appearing in your formula is then given by $$N(t)={n(t)\over|n(t)|}\ .$$
(ii) If $\Omega$ is given in the form
$$\Omega:=\bigl\{(x,y)\>\bigm|\>f(x,y)<c\bigr\}$$
with some smooth function $f$ then at any point $z_0\in\partial\Omega$ your vector $N(z_0)$ is given by
$$N(z_0)={\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\over|\nabla f(x_0,y_0)|}\ .$$